# Dis Alignment of bar chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render Bar chart with D3.js but facing the following alignment issue :

[image]

actually the data that I am trying to render is :

```
0: {year: "2011", count: 5462}
1: {year: "2012", count: 4984}
2: {year: "2013", count: 4980}
3: {year: "2014", count: 5244}
4: {year: "2015", count: 5181}
5: {year: "2016", count: 5084}
6: {year: "2017", count: 5354}
7: {year: "2018", count: 5927}
8: {year: "2019", count: 5659}
```

The code that I used to render the above chart is :

```
function render(data)
{   
const width = 400;
const height = 300;
const margin = {
    'top' : 100,
    'left' : 100,
    'right' : 100,
    'bottom' : 100
};
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const chartContainer = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
    .attr('class', 'holder');

const chart = chartContainer.select('g')
    .data(data)
    .enter();

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(obj => obj.year));

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0,d3.max(data, d => d.count) + 100]);

chartContainer.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

chartContainer.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));


chart.select('.holder')
.append('rect')
    .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.year))
    .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d.count))
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d.count))

 }
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not correctly mapped to each `rect` displaying the bars. If you tried `console.log(d)` when you render the `rect` objects, you will see that all `d` will be the of year 2019 and count 5659.

The correct way would be to create `chart` and the `rect` altogether. See the working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg></svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-55FY9DHtfMBE2epZhXrWn78so/ZT5/GCLim66+L83U5LghiYwVBAEris4/13Iab9S8C9ShJp3LQL/2raiaO+0w==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = [{year: "2011", count: 5462}, {year: "2012", count: 4984}
, {year: "2013", count: 4980}
, {year: "2014", count: 5244}
, {year: "2015", count: 5181}
, {year: "2016", count: 5084}
, {year: "2017", count: 5354}
, {year: "2018", count: 5927}
, {year: "2019", count: 5659}]
const width = 400;
const height = 300;
const margin = {
    'top' : 100,
    'left' : 100,
    'right' : 100,
    'bottom' : 100
};
const svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('height', height + margin.left + margin.right);
const chartContainer = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
    .attr('class', 'holder');



const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(data.map(obj => obj.year));

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0,d3.max(data, d => d.count) + 100]);

chartContainer.append('g')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

chartContainer.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

// render bars
const chart = chartContainer.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.year))
    .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d.count))
    .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d.count))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Result]